# How can I add image and Animation on React Konva, to work Simultaneously?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, react-konva, react-animations, react-canvas

The first image of contains a lion and an animated gif of yoda
[image: 1]

When I drag animated Yoda on canvas it turns into image, How can I make both animations and images work on Canvas.

I tried merging Animation code and image code, but didn't work.

Comment: What code did you try?